# How can I check the position of newly indexed pages within Google Search

Tags: google, google-search, keywords, search, ranking

**How can I check the position of newly indexed pages within Google Search**

Exactly what the title reads what is the best way of finding out the position and page number of newly indexed pages within Google Search.

Comment: Please reword your question. I have *no idea* what you mean by "put to a stand".

Comment: @Mike Hudson: I think he wants to find out his page SERP ranking.

Comment: You can run a search, then search the result pages. Do this from a private browsing session and you'll find an accurate result.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note... since Google's results vary according to where you are in the world, whatever tool you use needs to use the appropriate site for you or your customers location. For instance, if I'm in the UK then I probably want to be checking google.co.uk, not google.com.

It is also worth bearing in mind, when talking about page numbers, that whilst Google does default to showing 10 results per page, users can configure this to show up to 100 results per page (although not with Google instant enabled).

There are various tools/sites around that will do this for you, this one seems to do the job:
http://www.seoserp.com/web_tools/google_top_1000_serps_checker.asp